# How to run docker mongo standalone replSet?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to get `mongodb` running in docker, but something goes wrong.

the command:

```
docker run -i --rm \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example \
-p 27017:27017 \
-v keyFile:/etc/keyFile \
-v mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
-t mongo:latest --replSet rs0
```

**keyFile**

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > keyFile
```

**mongod.conf**

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
security:
  keyFile: /etc/keyFile
```

The problem lies in the following error of that command:

```
MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.

BadValue: security.keyFile is required when authorization is enabled with replica sets
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

How should one solve it?

Comment: The error indicates that the key file is not properly configured. You need to make sure that the keyFile is correctly configured in your mongod.conf file and that the path is correctly specified

Comment: @ManzoorSamad, There's `docker run` command provided with the `-v` linking, and I don't see there any issues.